# characters after whitespace missing - javascript

Tags: javascript

I am doing something like this:

```
 var MESSAGE = "part1 part2";
  var fName = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"fieldname\" size=35  disabled=disabled   value=" + MESSAGE + " />" );
```

the value of the textbox turns out to be "part1" and is missing part2. i.e the characters after the whitespace . What is the mistake here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add `"` to your value:

```
var MESSAGE = "part1 part2";
  var fName = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"fieldname\" size=35  disabled=disabled   value=\"" + MESSAGE + "\" />" );
```

Otherwise your browser interprets "part2" to be a new attribute like "class" or "size".

Answer (score 1):

One improvement could be to use the jQuery `.attr()` function, since it automatically escapes HTML entities such as `"`. It is recommended to do so, unless you are absolutely sure that your message doesn't contain any `"`,`<`or `>`.

```
var MESSAGE = "part1 part2";
var fName = $("<input">).attr({
    type     : "text",
    class    : "fieldname",
    size     : "35",
    disabled : "disabled",
    value    : MESSAGE
});
```

And now you are safe.